# Square wave, triangle wave etc. not defined in International Electrotechnical Vocabulary (IEV.) Are they not standard terminology?

Tags: waveform, terminology, standard

Why are there no definitions for typical terms like square wave, triangle wave etc. in the [*International Electrotechnical Vocabulary* (IEV)](http://www.electropedia.org/)?

Are these widely used descriptions not defined by international standards?

And if so:

Why?

Is there a more correct terminology one should use instead?

I have also searched through German standards and did not find any mention of terms like "Rechteckspannung" (square voltage) and the like.

Comment: A textbook would probably have a definition of the mathematical functions in terms of a Fourier series.  Does the IEV normally list mathematical functions?

Comment: Waveforms all have simple math formulae, but instruments have specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEV is intended as a resource for those who prepare standards for the use of electrical and electronic equipment.  It is not intended as a comprehensive vocabulary of electrical engineering. It does include many terms describing pulsed signals of which a square wave is a special case. One must conclude that, up to this time, there has been no need to define such terms in order to generate their technical standards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a widely used *exact* definition.

Does a square wave duty cycle have to be exactly 50%? If it is 49%, what is it?

Is a square and/or triangle wave centered on zero? Or is the lowest voltage zero?

If a specification needs to reference a waveform, it should use a diagram to unambiguously describe it. Examples below.

[image]